# @synthesize bar = __bar with two leading underscores?

Tags: objective-c, syntax

I learned, that it is (at least in most cases) a good propgramming style to synthesize a property in Objective-C this way:

```
@synthesite foo = _foo;
```

Today I encountered this line

```
@synthesite managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
```

in the file `AppDelegate.m` which is generated autmatically by Xcode.

*What is the main difference between **one** and **two** leading underscores?*

Comment: It's just inflation. In three year's time it'll be ________managedObjectContext

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question about @synthesize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112283/question-about-synthesize), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566594/what-is-this-double-underscore-in-cocoa, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851739/cocoa-variable-names, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9918567/single-and-double-underscore-difference-in-declaring-synthesize, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313642/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-objective-c, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258634/ivars-in-xcode-templates-prefixed-with-one-or-two-underscores

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference. It's just a matter of personal preference (just like adding the underscore to the ivar is to begin with; many people don't like it).

Comment: I would say there is a difference since the [C standard](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9918620/418715) says that double underscores are **Reserved**.

Comment: @Joe The compiler isn't going to complain if you use double underscores, and the program will function exactly the same way. Functionally there is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

There's no practical difference, though the double underscore is sometimes used in some languages to suggest that the variable is a "system" one rather than an application one.  It's a convention that never caught on in broad usage.